# Xamarin.IOS : MVVMCross Passing parameter from view to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross for my xamarin ios project. From my custom cell view, I want to pass a parameter to its view model. is it possible using MVVMCross?

I tried using CommandParameter property but it didn't work. Is it possible to pass parameters from view to viewmodel, If yes can someone provide a snippet?

Thank you

**Update**

My cell has button and on button click I want to know the cell index of the button being clicked to perform the operation. I am using the following code to do that.

```
this.DelayBind(() =>
{
    var bSet = this.CreateBindingSet<MyeCell, SomeViewModel>();
    bSet.Bind(cellIndex).To(vm => vm.index);
    bSet.Bind(UserPostBtn).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand);
    bSet.Apply();
});
```

I tried using delaybind to connect view and viewmodel but on button clickm I am getting the following error:

> invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

Comment: Do you want to pass the parameter on clicking the cell? Could you perhaps provide some code so we can see what you want to pass to your view model.

Comment: I updated my question @Plac3Hold3r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pass parameters to your `ViewModel` via a command using the `MvxCommandParameterValueConverter`.

***String name approach:***

```
bSet
    .Bind(UserPostBtn)
    .To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand)
    .WithConversion("CommandParameter", cellIndex);
```

***Typed name approach:***

```
bSet
    .Bind(UserPostBtn)
    .To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand)
    .WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), cellIndex);
```

***Extension method approach:***

```
bSet
    .Bind(MainButton)
    .To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand)
    .CommandParameter(cellIndex);
```

Then in your ViewModel receive the passed parameter.

```
IMvxCommand _editPhotoCommand;
public IMvxCommand EditPhotoCommand =>
    _editPhotoCommand ?? (_editPhotoCommand = new MvxCommand<int>(EditPhotoExecution));

private void EditPhotoExecution(int index)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

---

**Update:**

MvvmCross also provides an extension method, `CommandParameter`, that allows you to just pass in the command parameter and it will handle the creation of the `MvxCommandParameterValueConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [official documentation for MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tables-and-Cells-in-iOS) and how to work with UITableViews and UITableViewCells.

Basically, your `MvxTableViewSource` subclass gets notified about what cell got selected. Now it is just a matter of checking your model and matching the index...

If you need to know what text was entered or switch was flipped in you cell, you should consider using a binding between your cell subclass and your cell source. Make sure to use [`DelayBind`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/databinding) in your UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: I Used `DelayBind` but when I clicked on the button I got an error    `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.`

Comment: You should not bind it to the view model directly but to your source instead.